# Advanced count and join in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am try to find the top `n` number of categories as they relate to articles, there is a habtm relationship set up between the two. This is the SQL I want to execute, but am unsure of how to do this with ActiveRecord, aside from using the `find_by_sql` method. is there any way of doing this with ActiveRecord methods:

```
SELECT 
  "categories".id, 
  "categories".name, 
  count("articles".id) as counter 
FROM "categories"
JOIN "articles_categories" 
  ON "articles_categories".category_id = "categories".id
JOIN "articles" 
  ON "articles".id = "articles_categories".article_id
GROUP BY "categories".id
ORDER BY counter DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [find](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class) with options to achieve the same query:

```
Category.find(:all, 
  :select => '"categories".id, "categories".name, count("articles".id) as counter', 
  :joins => :articles, 
  :group => '"categories".id', 
  :order => 'counter DESC', 
  :limit => 5
)
```

Comment: Excellent thanks, thought I tried that but obviously I had something wrong in it

Comment: Any way to access the count value afterwards? `category= Category.find(...).first; category.counter`?